# how to loop through all subfolders images then display them

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder named:
'LIDC-IDRI' 
inside this folder I have some other folders named: 
'LIDC-IDRI-0001','LIDC-IDRI-0002','LIDC-IDRI-0003', ... 
each of these subfolders contains a number of images.

What I want to do is to iterate through all images inside all subfolders and display them using 'imshow' function, can anyone help me do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what have tried so far? please show some effort and people will be glad to help you

Comment: **@honar.cs**, nice question. I've tried to solve it and answered it. Please check and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

**@honar.cs**, based on your problem statement, I have tried to solve your problem.

> Here I want to display all the png and jpg images present inside `LIDC-IDRI-0001`, `LIDC-IDRI-0002`, `LIDC-IDRI-0003`, `LIDC-IDRI-0004` directories.

#### File structure »

```
H:\RISHIKESHAGRAWANI\PROJECTS\SOF\DISPLAYIMAGES
└───LIDC-IDRI
    │   show_images.md
    │   show_images.py
    │   show_images_temp.py
    │
    ├───LIDC-IDRI-0001
    │       download.jpg
    │       Hacker.jpg
    │
    ├───LIDC-IDRI-0002
    │       images.jpg
    │
    ├───LIDC-IDRI-0003
    │       internet.jpg
    │       Internet.png
    │
    └───LIDC-IDRI-0004
            RishikeshAgrawani-Hygull-Python.jpg
            wallpaper-strange-funny-weird-crazy-absurd-awesome-592.jpg
            waterfalls.jpg
```

#### Requirements »

- numpy - `pip install numpy`
- matplotlib - `pip install matplotlib`
- Pillow - `pip install Pillow`

#### » Python code (Python 3.6)

> show_images.py

```
import os
import json
import glob
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_formats = ["png", "jpg"]; # Let suppose we want to display png & jpg images (specify more if you want)

def show_images(image_file_name):
    print("Displaying ", image_file_name)
    img=mpimg.imread(image_file_name)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

def get_image_paths(current_dir):
    files = os.listdir(current_dir);
    paths = []; # To store relative paths of all png and jpg images

    for file in files:
        file = file.strip()
        if os.path.isdir(file) and 'LIDC-IDRI-' in file:
            for image_format in image_formats:
                image_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(".", file, "*." + image_format))
                if image_paths:
                    paths.extend(image_paths);

    return paths

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_paths = get_image_paths(".");
    print(json.dumps(image_paths, indent=4))

    # Display all images inside image_paths
    for image_path in image_paths:
        show_images(image_path);
        print('\n')
```

#### How to run?

Open terminal and navigate inside `LIDC-IDRI` directory using `cd` command and run the below command.

`python show_images.py`

#### Output on console »

> Images will be opened one by one (once you close 1st image, 2nd image will be displayed and so on).

```
[
    ".\\LIDC-IDRI-0001\\download.jpg",
    ".\\LIDC-IDRI-0001\\Hacker.jpg",
    ".\\LIDC-IDRI-0002\\images.jpg",
    ".\\LIDC-IDRI-0003\\Internet.png",
    ".\\LIDC-IDRI-0003\\internet.jpg",
    ".\\LIDC-IDRI-0004\\RishikeshAgrawani-Hygull-Python.jpg",
    ".\\LIDC-IDRI-0004\\wallpaper-strange-funny-weird-crazy-absurd-awesome-592.jpg",
    ".\\LIDC-IDRI-0004\\waterfalls.jpg"
]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, my images are '.dcm' and are all inside 'LIDC-IDRI-0001','LIDC-IDRI-0002',... folders, can you do it for dicom images?

Comment: Sure, I will  update my answer. I will let you know once done.